# React Native: detect if UIVisualEffectView is supported

Tags: ios, react-native, uivisualeffectview

I'd like to use [react-native-blur](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-blur) on my iOS app with React Native, using an alternative visualization on iOS 7 (such as a backgroundColor), which does not support `UIVisualEffectView`.

E.g.:

```
styles = { 
    backgroundColor: isVisualEffectViewSupported ? "transparent" : "rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
}
```

How can I detect if UIVisualEffectView is supported by the current platform?

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C:

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UIVisualEffectView");
if (cls) {
    // class exists, do whatever you need with it
} else {
    // class doesn't exists, fallback
}
```

Swift:

```
if NSClassFromString("UIVisualEffectView") != nil {
    println("UIVisualEffectView exists")
} else {
    println("UIVisualEffectView does not exists")
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, my question was for react-native. I've updated the title to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a native module which export iOS version to JS， then JS detect the version and decide if UIVisualEffectView is supported.